# Why is the Youtube likes playlist only returning "LL"?

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer

I'm using the youtube channels list API with the following parameters to get my liked videos playlist:
part: contentDetails,
mine: true

I get this response:

```json
"contentDetails": {
    "relatedPlaylists": {
        "likes": "LL",
        "uploads": "REDACTED"
```

Why is the likes playlist only providing "LL" instead of the playlist ID? Is it no longer supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed that's weird that YouTube use such custom PlayList ID and not common random one but you can still access to videos you liked by using the [PlayListItems: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) YouTube Data API v3 endpoint using `playlistId=LL` and not using `id`.

Comment: Cool, you're right, thanks!